# Using For Loop to edit multiple files

Tags: r

I have these files in a folder on my desktop: [image]

Using Rstudio, I am trying to create a for loop that can edit all of them in the same way as done for one file, Adipose-Subcutaneous_0.8125Pathway_Enrichment_all_results.xls, as shown here:

```
path = "/Users/cgill22/Desktop/GTEx_WGCNA_sex_combined_signed/Adipose-Subcutaneous_0.8125Pathway_Enrichment_all_results.xls"
name = sub(".*/", "", path)
name = sub("Pathway_Enrichment_all_results.xls.*", "", name)
name = gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "", name)
name = paste0(name, "sex-combined")
print(name)
```

Essentially so that the file can go from "Adipose-Subcutaneous_0.8125Pathway_Enrichment_all_results" to "Adipose-Subcutaneous_sex-combined".

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use a for-loop. I'd start with `list.files()`, to get the file names. You could then store the names in a vector and process them using `sapply()`. Or store them in a data frame and use `dplyr` function to process them.

It's difficult to test code without example data, but something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

files <- data.frame(filename = list.files("/Users/cgill22/Desktop/GTEx_WGCNA_sex_combined_signed",
                    pattern = "*.xls",
                    full.names = TRUE))

files <- files %>%
  mutate(newname = sub(".*/", "", filename),
         newname = sub("Pathway_Enrichment_all_results.xls.*", "", newname),
         newname = gsub("([0-9]+).*$", "", newname),
         newname = paste0(name, "sex-combined"))
```

Comment: Just tried it; it worked when instead of putting "newname" in the mutate() function, I put filename. Thank you!

Comment: My code puts the results in a new column `newname`, use `filename` if you want to modify the original column. Glad it helped: please accept the answer if it solved your problem.